# Ternary operator displays error in JSHint - Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript

I have a ternary operator `dir === 'next' ? ++$currentSlide : --$currentSlide;` in my JS used to increment of decrement an integer. when I run my script in grunt JSHint hightlights this line as `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.`

Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong with this? Should I set my condition up differently etc?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are misusing the conditional operator as an `if` statement, that's why you are getting that note. The real work in the code is done as a side effect of the expression, and the result of the expression is ignored.

As a real `if` statement, it would be:

```
if (dir === 'next') {
  ++$currentSlide;
} else {
  --$currentSlide;
}
```

You can use the conditional operator if you use it as an actual expression:

```
$currentSlide += dir === 'next' ? 1 : -1;
```

Comment: *Shudder* at the latter.

Comment: Won't you get the same warning for `++x;` on a line by itself?

Comment: @DaveNewton: `$currentSlide += dir === 'next' || -1;` :-)

Comment: @sje397 JSLint would complain about `++x`, but the more reasonable JSHint doesn't give a damn.

Comment: Or "dir" could be a function instead of a flag.

Comment: @Rob W - then isn't the explanation for the warning incorrect?

Comment: @sje397: Yes, technically it's also an expression with a side effect, but it's so often used and well known as it usually passes by as an exception.

Comment: @Guffa Ah...nothing is as simple as it seems :) Thanks.

Comment: `$currentSlide += dir === 'next' ? 1 : -1;` ? Didnt get this.

Answer (score 8):

In general, for disabling the 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.' warning, you can do /* jshint expr: true */

Answer (score 3):

Does it pass if you write it like this?

```
$currentSlide = (dir === 'next' ? $currentSlide + 1 : $currentSlide - 1);
```

Linters and hinters usually don't like in/decrements because they're sensitive to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
$currentSlide = (dir === 'next' ? $currentSlide+1 : $currentSlide-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

make ternary operator in to **`if else condition`**

**Before:**

```
(pbook.id === book.id ? book.shelf = pbook.shelf : "none");
```

**After:**

```
                     if(pbook.id === book.id){
                        return book.shelf = pbook.shelf
                      } else {
                        return "none"
                      };
```