# Why is Jshint alerting error on ternary operator statement?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-operator

I have this code in angularJS:

```
$scope.showForm = function(){
    $scope.formVisibility === false ? $scope.formVisibility = true : $scope.formVisibility = false;
};
```

however, I'm getting the last `false` boolean assignment highlighted as an warning, and not passing Grunt Jshint debugging.

VScode linting highlight and says the `false` last word and throws this: "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

What can be wrong in that ternary operator operation?

Comment: `$scope.formVisibility = !$scope.formVisibilty` would be a lot simpler

Comment: May be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060002/ternary-operator-displays-error-in-jshint-expected-an-assignment-or-function-c and  http://linterrors.com/js/expected-an-assignment-or-function-call can explain why you got this error