# Javascript ternary if statement, assigning it to a variable and incrementation

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, assign, ternary

So, I have this piece of code, which actually works:
(hash would be an object like this: {"bob" => "12, "Roger" => "15", etc}, and isGood(key) is a calling the function isGood that just returns if the player is good or bad)

```
let score = 0;
Object.keys(hash).forEach((key) => {
  isGood(key) === true ? score += parseInt(hash[key], 10) : score -= parseInt(hash[key], 10);
});
return score;
```

for which I get this error message:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
```

And I managed to make it work without getting this error message, like this:

```
let score = 0;
Object.keys(hash).forEach((key) => {
  score = isGood(key) ? score + parseInt(hash[key], 10) : score - parseInt(hash[key], 10);
});
return score;
```

But, why would the first one not be a proper way to do it, eventhough it works? I am sorry I have problems with conventions in Javascript.
Thanks in advance!
Olivier

Comment: A ternary needs a variable to store its result. This: `isGood(key) === true ?...` isn't assigned to `score` This: `score = isGood(key) ? ...` does assign the value to `score`.

Comment: `let change = parseInt(hash[key], 10); score += isGood(key) ? change : -change;` might be a more readable and less repetitive way to write this. Alternatively `return Object.entries(hash).reduce((score, [k, v]) => score + isGood(k) ? parseInt(v, 10) : -parseInt(v, 10))`

Comment: Thanks I get it now! Also thank you Stuart for introducing me to reduce, I will check it out more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid JavaScript code. I believe the error messages comes from jshint, which is a linter.

Here is a related answer:
[Ternary operator displays error in JSHint - Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18060002/783510)

In the end it is a matter of style, but having side-effects in a ternary operator is unexpected, which explains why a linter has rules to point it out. It makes it harder to reason about the code, so you would normally see an if-then-else construct instead.